# How do I compare the values of a column and then subtract values from the adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel, compare, subtraction

I have two worksheets. WS1 and WS2

WS1 - Column A and WS2 - Column A have product codes.
WS1 - Column B and WS2 - Column B have quantities ordered.

What I would like to do is Compare WS1-A to WS2-A.
If the strings match, then subtract WS2-B from WS1-B.
If no match then go to next row.

I found a bit of code, but since I'm new to VBA, I am not too sure how to modify it to meet my needs.

```
Public Sub CompareRange(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastrow2 As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim CompareCell As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim CellFound As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet12")

    lastRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow1)
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lastrow2)

    Set qty1 = ws1.Range("B1:B" & lastRow1)
    Set qtyair = ws2.Range("B1:B" & lastrow2)

    For Each CompareCell In rng1.Cells
        CellFound = False
        For Each CheckCell In rng2.Cells
            If CheckCell.Text = CompareCell.Text Then

            End If
        Next CheckCell
        If Not CellFound Then
        End If
    Next CompareCell
End Sub
```

Kindly advise on how I can get this done in Excel VBA. I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, could you not just use a `VLOOKUP` and `IFERROR` function together to lookup the value and subtract if it does exist. If if doesn't exist do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
sub match_col()

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet12")

lastRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1 to lastRow1
j = 1 to lastRow2

if worksheets("ws1_A").range("a" & i).value =  worksheets("ws2_A").range("a" & i).value 

msgBox worksheets("ws2_B").range("B" & i).value - worksheets("ws1_B").range("B" & i).value

end if
next j
next i
```